# How to convert a date in Databricks SQL to a Datetime (timestamp) of the last second of the day?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a date field in the SQL / Spark table I am querying. e.g. 2022-03-01
I want to extract a datetime / timestamp of the last second for that date - i.e. 2022-03-01 23:59:59

How best to achieve this - specifically in Spark SQL (although I am also interested to see equivalent solutions for SQL Server syntax - I currently use DATEADD and add 86399 seconds to the date which is a bit clunky)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a similar thing with Spark here, since you have a `DateType` you would have to convert it to an intermediate source before you append the `time` component

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
date_str
2022-03-01
2022-05-20
2022-06-21
2022-10-22
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter=',')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)\
             .withColumn('date_parsed',F.to_date(F.col('date_str'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))\

sparkDF.registerTempTable("TB1")

sparkDF.show()

sparkDF.printSchema()

+----------+-----------+
|  date_str|date_parsed|
+----------+-----------+
|2022-03-01| 2022-03-01|
|2022-05-20| 2022-05-20|
|2022-06-21| 2022-06-21|
|2022-10-22| 2022-10-22|
+----------+-----------+

root
 |-- date_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_parsed: date (nullable = true)
```

#### Unix Timestamp

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn("date_time", (F.unix_timestamp("date_parsed") + 86399).cast('timestamp'))

sparkDF.show()

+----------+-----------+-------------------+
|  date_str|date_parsed|          date_time|
+----------+-----------+-------------------+
|2022-03-01| 2022-03-01|2022-03-01 23:59:59|
|2022-05-20| 2022-05-20|2022-05-20 23:59:59|
|2022-06-21| 2022-06-21|2022-06-21 23:59:59|
|2022-10-22| 2022-10-22|2022-10-22 23:59:59|
+----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

#### SparkSQL

```
sql.sql(
    """
        SELECT
            date_str,
            CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE(date_str,'yyyy-MM-dd')) + 86399 AS TIMESTAMP) as date_time
        FROM TB1
    """
).show()

+----------+-------------------+
|  date_str|          date_time|
+----------+-------------------+
|2022-03-01|2022-03-01 23:59:59|
|2022-05-20|2022-05-20 23:59:59|
|2022-06-21|2022-06-21 23:59:59|
|2022-10-22|2022-10-22 23:59:59|
+----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: If its a string , you can just concat the time part of the col to generate the required result

Comment: The input field is a date (not a string) in the underlying Spark table.  The conversion I am looking for is Date to DateTime, not String to DateTime.

I'll try your 3rd suggestion (SparkSQL) with an amendment to address this fact.

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MyDate) + 86399 as TS1 works okay, but 
CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MyDate) + 86399 AS TIMESTAMP) as TS1 throws an error:


IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type N

Comment: the answers demonstrate a DateType to TimestampType conversion , you can check the schema as well as the output from your end , under data preparation I implicitly converted a `date_str` to `date`

Comment: add sample towards your input , and the stack trace under the question